# Django admin form : dynamic fields list causes a KeyError which I can bypass just by pressing F5, why?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Before exposing my bug, let me explain what I am trying to acheive.

### Problem

In the django admin, when editing an object, I want the fields list to change according to the kind of object (defined by the field `kind`). For example, I have a blog post model:

```
KIND_LIST = (
    ('featured', 'Featured'),
    ('classic', 'Classic'),
)

class Post(models.Model):
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=KIND_LIST)
    attribut1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attribut2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

When I am editing an *featured* post, I want do display only `attribut1` and when I want to display a *classic* post, I want to display only `attribut2`.

### My solution

I override `get_form` so I can exclude some fields.

```
class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(PollAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if obj and obj.kind == 'featured':
            self.exclude = ('attribut2',)
        elif obj and obj.kind == 'classic':
            self.exclude = ('attribut1',)
        return form

admin.site.register(BlogPost, BlogPostAdmin)
```

### The bug

At first sight, it works, but on a specific use case, I got a bug. When I edit a *featured* post and **then** a *classic* post I got this error:

```
KeyError at /admin/blog/post/1/
u"Key 'attribut2' not found in Form"
```

It didn't found the field to display. But, a simple F5 and it works again! I suppose there is some sort of cache somewhere because when I am editing only the same kind of post I don't get an error.

Does anyone can help me and explain me why I got this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is working code:

```
class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            if obj.kind == 'featured':
                self.exclude = ('attribut2',)
            elif obj.kind == 'classic':
                self.exclude = ('attribut1',)
        else:
            self.exclude = None

        return super(BlogPostAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Post, BlogPostAdmin)
```

I get the gist of why it works, but I'm not going to pretend to be smart enough to understand it fully. Maybe somebody can comment and explain why it works.